# the Firebase Realtime database rules are changing from true to false automatically how to fix it?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTboE.png)

My Firebase realtime database rules are changing from this

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

to this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

By the way, I'm using Firebase's realtime database to display ads in my android app.

Answer (score 7):

Rules don't change automatically.  Either someone is changing them in the console, or someone is running `firebase deploy` on the command line which is deploying new rules from their machine (usually from a file called firebase.rules) from the Firebase CLI project directory.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer no one have access  to my firebase console

Comment: If you don't know where the change is coming from, there's not much Stack Overflow can do for you.  I've given primary two way that rules can change.  If it's not either of those, then you should contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: thanks, fixed my problem (new firebase user)! after deply, the db rules were always changed- because my local database.rules.json rules are false :)

Comment: Mine were changing due to firebase deploy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase realtime database rules can be updated from multiple areas, including the Firebase project page and from the Firebase CLI. One potential reason for this issue could be that you are accidentally overwriting your rules.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/get-started):

> To view your existing Rules, use either the Firebase CLI or the
> Firebase console. Make sure you edit your rules using the same method,
> consistently, to avoid mistakenly overwriting updates. If you're not
> sure whether your locally defined rules reflect the most recent
> updates, the Firebase console always shows the most recently deployed
> version of your Firebase Security Rules.